# Compact set has supporting hyperplane parallel to any hyperplane $H$?

Tags: convex-analysis

> Let $E$ be a non-empty compact set and $H$ is any hyperplane. Show that $E$ has a supporting hyperplane parallel to $H$.

I have no idea to proceed the proof. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to say that $E$ is convex or not ? Is the space euclidean ?

Comment: $E$ is not necessary to be convex. Space is Euclidean. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all remember that, in finite dimensions, every linear functional is continuous.

Let $p \cdot x=\alpha$ be an equation of $H$.

Since $E$ is compact, the continuous linear functional $x \rightarrow p \cdot x$ has a minimum $\beta$ and a maximum $\gamma$ in $E$.

Thus $\beta \le p \cdot x \le \gamma$ for every $x \in E$ and there exist $x_1,x_2\in E$ with $p \cdot x_1=\beta$ and $p \cdot x_2=\gamma$.

If $\beta < \gamma$, there are two supporting hyperplanes parallel to $H$.

If $\beta = \gamma$, the solution is unique ($E$ is contained in it).

All this paraphrased from M. Florenzano,C. Le Van *Finite $\,$Dimensional Convexity and Optimization* (2001), Proposition 2.1.2, p. 22 . On p. 21 you find the definitions you need.